# Kinetic JS not working in Firefox

Tags: php, kineticjs

I have used one script. My problem is script is not working in Firefox browser.

Code is here:

```
window.onload = function(){
        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
            container : "cantainer",
            width : 400,
            height : 400
        });
        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
        stage.add(layer);
        var con = stage.getContainer();    
        var dragSrcEl = null;
        //image
        document.getElementById("yoda").addEventListener('dragstart',function(e){
               dragSrcEl = this;
        });

        con.addEventListener('dragover',function(e){
            e.preventDefault(); //@important
        });
        //insert image to stage
        con.addEventListener('drop',function(e){
            var image = new Kinetic.Image({
               draggable : true
            });
            layer.add(image);
            imageObj = new Image();
            imageObj.src = dragSrcEl.src;
            imageObj.onload = function(){
                image.setImage(imageObj)
                layer.draw()
            };
         });
```

Check the script on link: http://jsfiddle.net/lavrton/n4w44/

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
e.preventDefault();
```

inside `drop` event listener.
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bk86e/